# Firing off events on multiple click events JS

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, counter

I am building a booking system where I am currently attempting to connect all different steps with one another. I would like to connect them through "previous" and "next" buttons, where I implemented a switch statement that counts the clicks and hides/shows a certain step accordingly.

However, I realised the switch statement doesn't make much sense anymore since the user might click on both previous **and** next buttons more than the cases I've set up. I've pasted my current code below, I know there must be a shorter way but I am not sure how to connect these two buttons to work as they should.

Ideally, I would need different events to be fired off on different clicks.

**HTML code**:

```
<div class="bookingArea">
        <div id="bookingOverlay" class="overlay">
            <button id="bookBtn">Click to book!</button>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <hr>
                <div class="bookingSteps">
                </div>
                <!-- AVAILABILITY -->
                <form class="availability step1">
                </form>
                <!-- buttons -->
                <button class="previous hide">Previous</button>
                <button class="next">Next</button>
                <!-- PERSONAL DATA -->
                <form class="personalData step2">
                </form>
                <!-- ORDER OVERVIEW -->
                <div class="orderOverview step3">
                </div>
                <!-- PAYMENT -->
                <form class="payment step4">
                </form>
                <!-- RECEIPT -->
                <div class="receipt step5">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS code:**

```js
// activate "next" btn
var counter = 0;

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', function () {

    document.querySelector(".previous").classList.remove("hide");

    switch (++counter) {
        case 1:
            document.querySelector(".availability").classList.add("step1");
            document.querySelector(".personalData").classList.remove("step2");
            return +counter;
        case 2:
            document.querySelector(".personalData").classList.add("step2");
            document.querySelector(".orderOverview").classList.remove("step3");
            return +counter;
        case 3:
            document.querySelector(".orderOverview").classList.add("step3");
            document.querySelector(".payment").classList.remove("step4");
            return +counter;
        case 4:
            document.querySelector(".payment").classList.add("step4");
            document.querySelector(".receipt").classList.remove("step5");
            return +counter;
    }
    counter = 0;
});

// activate "previous" btn
var counter = 0;

document.querySelector(".previous").addEventListener('click', function () {
    switch (++counter) {
        case 1:
            return +counter;
        case 2:
            document.querySelector(".availability").classList.remove("step1");
            document.querySelector(".personalData").classList.add("step2");
            console.log("2");
            return +counter;
        case 3:
            document.querySelector(".personalData").classList.remove("step2");
            document.querySelector(".orderOverview").classList.add("step3");
            console.log("3");
            return +counter;
        case 4:
            document.querySelector(".orderOverview").classList.remove("step3");
            document.querySelector(".payment").classList.add("step4");
            console.log("4");
            return +counter;
        case 5:
            document.querySelector(".payment").classList.remove("step4");
            document.querySelector(".receipt").classList.add("step5");
            console.log("5");
            return +counter;
    }
    counter = 0;
});
```

Comment: Can you share your html as well?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan It's in the post now:)

Comment: Your code is really looking messy, you want to show a specific field by clicking on prev or next button, don't you?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Yes, I realised, I just cleaned it up. And yes, exactly

Comment: Just have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution. The ideas are as follows:

1. I've added the same class named `show` to all of your forms except the first one and by adding CSS, I've set `display: none;` to that class.
2. Then increase or decrease the counter between 1 and 5 because our total steps are 5.
3. Just add or remove the class **`show`** according to the counter.

I've added some comments to understand better. Just have a look at the code snippet below:

```js
var counter = 1, step = "step";

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', function () {

    step = ".step" + counter;

    if (counter <= 5) {
        document.querySelector(step).classList.add("show");
    }

    counter++;

    if (counter > 5) {
        counter = 5;
    }

    step = ".step" + counter; // step is the class and we are appending counter with step so that it looks like the same class in the given class(like counter 1 means step1)
    //console.log(step);

    document.querySelector(step).classList.remove("show");
});

document.querySelector(".previous").addEventListener('click', function () {

    if (counter > 1) { // we don't want to remove the first step, it will always be shown
        step = ".step" + counter;
        //console.log(step);

        document.querySelector(step).classList.add("show");
    }

    counter--;

    if (counter < 1) {
        counter = 1;
    }


    step = ".step" + counter;

    document.querySelector(step).classList.remove("show");

});
```

```css
.show {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookingArea">
    <div id="bookingOverlay" class="overlay">
        <button id="bookBtn">Click to book!</button>
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <hr>
            <div class="bookingSteps">
            </div>
            <!-- AVAILABILITY -->
            <form class="availability step1">
                <h1>step1</h1>
            </form>
            <!-- buttons -->
            <button class="previous">Previous</button>
            <button class="next">Next</button>
            <!-- PERSONAL DATA -->
            <form class="personalData step2 show">
                <h1>step2</h1>
            </form>
            <!-- ORDER OVERVIEW -->
            <div class="orderOverview step3 show">
                <h1>step3</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- PAYMENT -->
            <form class="payment step4 show">
                <h1>step4</h1>
            </form>
            <!-- RECEIPT -->
            <div class="receipt step5 show">
                <h1>step5</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to help me. I implemented your code and it seems like the buttons are working as I would like them to, however, the "old" step won't disappear when clicking on next, and vice-versa. Basically, the steps just keep adding up, which is not the intention. I probably didn't specify that before, sorry.

Comment: Ok, got it. You want the previous step to be hidden with showing the current one, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much, I really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: @meganelondono, my pleasure :)